# WSO2 IS and APIM Scopes and Roles

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

I'm setting up a wso2 apim with wso2 is as key manager.
I would like only users with a certain role to be able to get scope on IS.

For example, if I have a role X and the user USER has the role X only this user must be able to obtain the relative scope, which will then be used by APIM to access the resource, is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible.

As the first step, you need to create different roles/ groups in the user store using the Carbon console.

Next, you need to do the role-user mapping using the Carbon console.

Next, you need to create a new Global Scope using the Publisher portal and associate it with the role/ group.

As the final step, you need to associate your newly created Scope with whatever resources you need to protect with this scope.

For more information - https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/design/api-security/oauth2/oauth2-scopes/fine-grained-access-control-with-oauth-scopes/

Comment: Could you be more specific?
I didn't understand well, consider that the key is generated by IS, so I guess the role must be created on IS too